# Append spaces in the end of line by using printf function in unix

Tags: printf

I have the following script running in unix which suppose padding 9 spaces in the end of a line.  However, the output result were not as I expected.

```
# define SPACE " "

void main {
  printf("%13s%9s\n", "Output 1: 123", SPACE);
  printf("%13s%-9s\n", "Output 2: 123", SPACE);
  printf("%13s%9s%1s\n", "Output 3: 123", SPACE, "|");
  printf("%13s%-9s%1s\n", "Output 4: 123", SPACE, "|");
}
```

The result:

```
Output 1: 123
Output 2: 123
Output 3: 123         |
Output 4: 123         |
```

The output 1 and 2 trim the spaces in the end, the output 3 and 4 has the 9 spaces if I put something behind.

How to show "Output 1: 123         "?

cheer